# Yii2 Using ArrayHelper::map, return child on third parameter

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have two tables with design master detail.

The master table is named `Format2006FlatFileMaster`.

The detail table is named `Format2006FlatFileDetail`.

My goal is, I want to use a field as key and the value is their child of master.

I mean like this

```
$details = ArrayHelper::map(Format2006FlatFileMaster::find()->all(), 'alias', function ($model) {
        $model->format2006FlatFileDetails;
});
```

I got like this data, (For ex, this is dummy data)

```
'details' => [
    'HDR01' => [
        0 => app\models\utilities\Format2006FlatFileDetail#1
        (
            [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => [
                'id' => 1
                '2006_flat_file_master_id' => 1
                'field_name' => 'Record Lable'
                'start' => 1
                'width' => 5
                'decimal' => null
                'type' => 'C'
                'mandatory' => 'Y'
                'note' => 'HDR01'
            ]
            [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_oldAttributes] => [
                'id' => 1
                '2006_flat_file_master_id' => 1
                'field_name' => 'Record Lable'
                'start' => 1
                'width' => 5
                'decimal' => null
                'type' => 'C'
                'mandatory' => 'Y'
                'note' => 'HDR01'
            ]
            [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_related] => []
            [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_relationsDependencies] => []
            [yii\base\Model:_errors] => null
            [yii\base\Model:_validators] => null
            [yii\base\Model:_scenario] => 'default'
            [yii\base\Component:_events] => []
            [yii\base\Component:_eventWildcards] => []
            [yii\base\Component:_behaviors] => []
        )
        1 => app\models\utilities\Format2006FlatFileDetail#2
        (
            [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_attributes] => [
                'id' => 2
                '2006_flat_file_master_id' => 1
                'field_name' => 'Message Function Code'
                'start' => 6
                'width' => 1
                'decimal' => null
                'type' => ''
                'mandatory' => 'Y'
                'note' => '1 Original 2 Update (handle manually) 3 Consolidation (handle manually)'
            ]
            [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_oldAttributes] => [
                'id' => 2
                '2006_flat_file_master_id' => 1
                'field_name' => 'Message Function Code'
                'start' => 6
                'width' => 1
                'decimal' => null
                'type' => ''
                'mandatory' => 'Y'
                'note' => '1 Original 2 Update (handle manually) 3 Consolidation (handle manually)'
            ]
            [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_related] => []
            [yii\db\BaseActiveRecord:_relationsDependencies] => []
            [yii\base\Model:_errors] => null
            [yii\base\Model:_validators] => null
            [yii\base\Model:_scenario] => 'default'
            [yii\base\Component:_events] => []
            [yii\base\Component:_eventWildcards] => []
            [yii\base\Component:_behaviors] => []
        )
    ]
]
```

As you can see, the data on the third parameter is in array objects,
I need in array format like this.

```
'details' => [
    'HDR01' => [
        0 => [
            'id' => 1
            '2006_flat_file_master_id' => 1
            'field_name' => 'Record Lable'
            'start' => 1
            'width' => 5
            'decimal' => null
            'type' => 'C'
            'mandatory' => 'Y'
            'note' => 'HDR01'
        ],
        1 => [
            'id' => 2
            '2006_flat_file_master_id' => 1
            'field_name' => 'Message Function Code'
            'start' => 6
            'width' => 1
            'decimal' => null
            'type' => ''
            'mandatory' => 'Y'
            'note' => '1 Original 2 Update (handle manually) 3 Consolidation (handle manually)'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Please Advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [`ArrayHelper::toArray()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#toArray()-detail) to convert object to array:

```
$details = ArrayHelper::map(Format2006FlatFileMaster::find()->all(), 'alias', function ($model) {
    return ArrayHelper::toArray($model->format2006FlatFileDetails);
});
```

Comment: Nice answer..:)

Answer (score 1):

you can resolve this issue by declare a new relation method in your `Format2006FlatFileMaster` with name `format2006FlatFileDetailsAsArray`, and this method will has an `asArray`, by `asArray` the response for relation will retrieve as an array as you want.

or another way:
You can use Join/JoinWith in query nested of using model->relation, in this way you can set `asArray` direct and got array too... like this:

```
$query = yourModel::find()
   ->joinWith([....])
   ->andWhere(....)
   ->asArray()->all();
```

Note: You can test `Format2006FlatFileMaster::find()->asArray()->all()` too, maybe its will resolve your issue too, but Im not sure.

Regards,